# Return multiple arrays to the main method

Tags: java

My program is suppose to take a text file, read the first four names, create a random number between 1-4, and then assign the names to 4 different teams based on what the random number was. For instance, if the number was 3, then the first name would go to team 3, second name to team 4, etc. etc.(repeat process until there are no more names) I believe I have all of the code for that correct, the problem is I can't figure out how to return all the names I have put into the arrays that were brought into the method. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
BufferedReader girlFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("girls40.txt"));
PrintWriter teamFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("xxxxxxx-teamlist.txt"));
String team1[] = new String[20];
String team2[] = new String[20];
String team3[] = new String[20];
String team4[] = new String[20];
int n;

n = loadTeams(team1,team2,team3,team4,girlFile);
girlFile.close();
teamFile.close();
}

public static String[] loadTeams(String team1[],String team2[],String team3[],String team[],BufferedReader girlFile)
{
int n;
int random;
String name1;
String name2;
String name3;
String name4;
while((name1=girlFile.readLine())!=null)
  {
    name2=girlFile.readLine();
    name3=girlFile.readLine();
    name4=girlFile.readLine();
    random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 4);
    if(random==1)
      {
        team1[n]=name1;
        team2[n]=name2;
        team3[n]=name3;
        team4[n]=name4;
      }
    if(random==2)
      {
        team1[n]=name4;
        team2[n]=name1;
        team3[n]=name2;
        team4[n]=name3;
      }
    if(random==3)
      {
        team1[n]=name3;
        team2[n]=name4;
        team3[n]=name1;
        team4[n]=name2;
      }
    if(random==4)
      {
        team1[n]=name2;
        team2[n]=name3;
        team3[n]=name4;
        team4[n]=name1;
      }
    n++;  
  }
return team1[],team2[],team3[],team4[];
  }`
```

The main method was given to me, so it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If there is more code in `main` method than you've posted here. You'll have to mention what is the variable `n` and how is it being used else follow the answer.

**`main` Method can't be changed**

In your main method,

```
int n;

n = loadTeams(team1,team2,team3,team4,girlFile);
girlFile.close();
teamFile.close();
} // End of Main Method
```

You have not used returned value `n` for nothing. So it really doesn't matter what you return from method `loadTeams()` as long as it is an `int`.

Also, here `loadTeams()` returns an `String[]` which can't be assigned be `int n`, you'll have to change return type of `loadTeams()` to `int` as

```
public static int loadTeams(String team1[],String team2[],String team3[],String team[],BufferedReader girlFile) {
/* 
   ...
 */
      return 0; // whatever, it isn't being used
}
```

**This the solution if you can't change the `main` method.**

Answer (score 0):

The call to `loadTeams()` expects a return value of type `int`. Not an array or multiple arrays. If you can't change the main method then `loadTeams` should return an integer.

```
// ...
int n;
n = loadTeams(team1,team2,team3,team4,girlFile);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to return anything, arrays created in main() will be passed to your method by reference, you can fill them there, and after execution of your method, values will be kept in these arrays

Answer (score 0):

1. The **`loadTeams`** should return an **`int`** and not **`String[]`**.
2. There is no need to return arrays. Changes made in the arrays in the **`loadTeams`** methods will be reflected back to the array in main method.